# A few questions about a Probability problem involving airline flights and using the phrase "or fewer".

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

The question goes as follows:

An airline reports that $77.5\%$ of its flights arrive on time. A check of $200$ randomly selected airline flights shows that $140$ of them arrived on time. Estimate the probability that among $200$ airline flights, $140$ or fewer arrive on time. Based on this result, does it seem plausible that the claimed on-time rate of $77.5\%$ could be correct?

I have tried to workout the problem and ended up with a probability of $0.0055$ ($Z$ score is $-2.54$) Given I worked out these values: $n=200$, $p= 0.775$, and $q= 0.225$, the mean is $155$, and the standard deviation is: $5.906$.

My question(s) are:

- Am I going about this question correctly assuming that $n>30$ (central limit theorem)?
- And how does one know when to use the greater than/greater than or equal...less than/less than or equal to signs when working these problems?

I had used $P(x \leq 140)$ while setting up this particular problems, but I am still somewhat struggling on how to correctly interpret word problems. Thank you for your time.

Comment: $P(x \le 140)$ is indeed the probability they're asking you to estimate. Since it's an _estimation_, you should use the Central limit theorem, as the distribution you're trying to estimate is equal to the sum of 200 Bernoullis, well over 30

Answer (score 1):

The *approximate* probability of $140$ or less flights arriving on time, assuming a Normal($155, 5.906^2)$ distribution is: $$\mathsf P(x < 140.5)\approx 0.339$$

Note: the $.5$ adend is because our variable actually realises discrete (integer) values while the Normal approximation is a continuous distribution; so we cover the pre-rounding values.